# Shallow copying with primitives

Tags: java

From what I understand about Java (which is arguably pretty little =P), Java treats primitive values differently than objects. One example I can think of is that primitives are passed by value, while objects are passed via the value of their references.

Extending this, I have implemented code that creates an array of int, and shallow copied it over to a new array of int:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {2,3,4,5};
    int[] copy = array;
    copy[1] = 0;

    for (int i : copy){
        System.out.print(i);}
    System.out.println();

    for (int i : array){
        System.out.print(i);}
}
}
```

However, the output is:

```
2045
2045
```

So, what puzzles me is why do both arrays change? I thought when we made a copy of the original array, we only copied over the values of the elements (since we are dealing with primitives)?

Comment: no, you just created a second reference pointing to the same array.

Comment: ooooooh that makes so much sense. So it seems that if I were to make a new int[] copy and copy over each element individually from array into copy with a for loop, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: indeed. a bit more wok, but it would solve your issue

Comment: awesome, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy the array at all. What you did was make the references `array` and `copy` point to the same array in memory. Thus, when you change the array via one reference, the other reference will point to the same change.

Comment: yes it seems I made a mistake and only copied the reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects. When you set

```
int[] copy = array;
```

both `copy` and `array` refer to the same object. Your update

```
copy[1] = 0;
```

updates "both".

Answer (score 0):

When you made the assignment `copy[1] = 0`, you told Java to take the array which `copy` refers to, go to position 1, and assign the value 0.  Since you also have the following statement

```
int[] copy = array;
```

then `copy` and `array` refer to the same array in memory.  You never really made a shallow copy, you only assigned another variable to point to the same array.

If you want to make a copy of the array, then you could try:

```
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
```